# Do I need a temporary car insurance and how to get one?

Tags: driving, insurance, texas

I'm in Texas, USA and I'm traveling to a different city where I'm going to be driving a friend's car for a few days. I hold a valid drivers license but no car insurance of my own.

Am I required to have insurance? My friend has his.
If yes, which companies offer one?

I looked at Geico and Nationwide but they don't seem to offer temporary insurance.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about travelling within the scope of the site. It's a question about everyday life, like "How do I drive a car?"

Comment: But, yes, you're surely required to have insurance to cover your personal liability arising from what might happen when you're on the road. We don't give product recommendations.

Comment: Talk to your friend. His policy may already cover you, or it's likely that he can arrange for his insurance company to cover you on his policy for a short period..

Comment: @DavidRicherby No, it's definitely on-topic.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I would believe that it is on topic. I’m an international student living in Texas and have never owned anything that would require me to get insurance. I’m therefore unfamiliar with car ownership and other stuff that comes along with it.

Comment: @BinoyDalal Questions about living in a foreign country are explicitly off-topic.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I think I should have described better. I’m traveling to my friend’s city also in Texas for a few days and hence the question. I’ll edit the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the United States, most car insurance policies cover "permissive users," those who the named insured allow to drive the named insured's vehicle. The terms of the named insured's insurance policy will actually control. Read the policy, or have the named insured ask his or her insurance agent if the policy covers permissive users.

Comment: He checked for this and his policy covers me. Thanks for the tip on permissive users.

Comment: Make sure your license is valid for use in the state(s) where you’ll drive. This is apt to require an International Driving Permit, a translation of your license when the license is in non-Roman characters.